# Run a custom config on Heroku for my flask app

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Hi Good people i need to ask a question on how to run a custom command on heroku for my Flask APP it runs on my local machine. Need to run this command either on gunicorn or just locally.

```
 $export FLASK_CONFIG = development
 $export FLASK_APP = run.py
 flask run
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use class based configs. this, allow you to have different config values for different environments(production, development, test, etc).

Here is a link to flask documentation on how to do class based configuration.[Development / Production](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/#development-production)

`config.py`:

```
class Config():
    DEBUG = True

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    #stuff you like!
```

using gunicorn, you can create a WSGI entry point and initialize the app so it start's the app using that specific configuration.

`application.py`:

```
from project.config import ProductionConfig
app = create_app(ProductionConfig)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=app.config['PORT'])
```

starting gunicorn processes with this type of application creation, you can use specific class of settings.

```
gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:4000 application:app
```